# Extra info on KendoUI bulletchart

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui

I'd like to add some extra information to my bullet chart.
I've set the currentField, targetField and category.
I couldn't see much in the kendoUI documentation.

I'd like to display extra information on my tooltip. Information is passed through with the json object.

I've tried a few different things, for example adding the RepName into the tooltip like this:

`template: "Target: #= value.target #%<br /> Actual: #= value.current #% RepName: #= RepName #"`

If this information can't actually be passed, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}%",
                template: "#= series.field #: #= value #,#= series.field #: #= value.target  #%"
            }
```

demo:http://jsbin.com/uriwaj/1/edit